# WebView page count

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have a `WebView` that displays some content, which is frequently updated. I would like to display a page counter in my UI which would tell the user how many pages would web view have if they would to print it.

I have tried doing:

```
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
BOOL knows = [[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] knowsPageRange: &r];
```

which gives `knows = YES` but `r.length` always equals 1.

How can I get at this information? (Preferably in a performant way, if possible).

Comment: This is a primarily OSX question, please take that into consideration when editing.

Comment: Just an idea, don't have any code. You could print it as a `pdf` in the background and count those pages.

Comment: @HAS That might work, though it seems like a pretty slow way to go about it. I'm doing this several times per second.

Comment: That's really often! Than this is your last resort ;)

Answer (score 2):

Not a perfectly elegant solution, but a possibility could include:

```
NSString *heightStr = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]; // Get the height of our webView
int height = [heightStr intValue];

CGFloat maxHeight   = kDefaultPageHeight - 2*kMargin;
CGFloat maxWidth    = kDefaultPageWidth - 2*kMargin;
int pages = ceil(height / maxHeight);
return pages;
```

via [Chris Mills' blog.](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/making-a-pdf-from-a-uiwebview/)

Comment: This is my current solution, although I get the `height` by a perhaps more elegant `[[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] bounds].size.height`. The problem with this is that the WebView itself may be resized to a different width than a printed page making the content reflow differently and being of a very different height.